# script busca - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

O problema é que não consigo separar o `arquivo_novo` do `/root/arquivo_novo`, conforme indicado abaixo. Preciso apenas do "arquivo_novo" para conseguir entrar no *LOOP IF* e o sistema retorna `/root/arquivo_novo` e nunca entra no *LOOP IF*. Não posso considerar o `/root/` pois não sei onde o arquivo estará.

```
>>> subprocess.call(["find / -iname arquivo*],shell=True)
>>> /root/**arquivo_novo**
>>> 0
>>>
>>> subprocess.check_output(["find / -iname arquivo*"],shell=True)
>>> b'/root/**arquivo_novo**\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código abaixo, `#1` captura a saída do comando como você mesmo sugeriu. Depois usamos a `#2` função do módulo `os` para separar o nome base do caminho absoluto. Que nada mais é do que passar o caminho absoluto para
'/tmp/file.py'.split('/')[-1]

```
>>> path = subprocess.check_output(["find / -iname arquivo*"], shell=True) #encontrado /tmp/file.py #1

>>> import os
>>> file_name = os.path.basename(path) #2

>>> file_name
>>> b'aquivo.py'
>>> #decodificar
>>> file_name.decode('utf-8')
>>> 'aquivo.py'
```

Comment: Há algum livro ou material que oriente a criação de scripts em linux?

Comment: Linux a Bíblia e Python fluente são livros ótimos.